# TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to loop over elements of an input string, and get them from a dictionary. What am I doing wrong?

```
number_map = { 1: -3, 2: -2, 3: -1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 3 }
input_str = raw_input("Enter something: ")
strikes = [number_map(int(x)) for x in input_str.split()]
```

---

```
strikes  = [number_map(int(x)) for x in input_str.split()]
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: From the example you gave it looks like an array would be better for this task.

Answer (score 70):

The syntax for accessing a dict given a key is to **use square brackets**:

```
number_map[int(x)]
          ^      ^
```

`number_map(int(x))` (with parentheses) would actually be a function call but since `number_map` is not a callable, an exception is raised.

Answer (score 34):

Access the dictionary with square brackets.

```
strikes = [number_map[int(x)] for x in input_str.split()]
```

Answer (score 24):

You need to use `[]` to access elements of a dictionary. Not `()`

```
  number_map = { 1: -3, 2: -2, 3: -1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 3 }
input_str = raw_input("Enter something: ")
strikes = [number_map[int(x)] for x in input_str ]
```

Answer (score 11):

```
strikes  = [number_map[int(x)] for x in input_str.split()]
```

You get an element from a *dict* using these **`[]`** brackets, not these **`()`**.

Answer (score 9):

```
strikes  = [number_map[int(x)] for x in input_str.split()]
```

Use square brackets to explore dictionaries.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use:

```
number_map[int(x)]
```

Note the square brackets!

Answer (score 2):

A more functional approach would be by using `dict.get`

```
input_nums = [int(in_str) for in_str in input_str.split())
strikes = list(map(number_map.get, input_nums.split()))
```

One can observe that the conversion is a little clumsy, better would be to use the abstraction of [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition):

```
def compose2(f, g):
    return lambda x: f(g(x))

strikes = list(map(compose2(number_map.get, int), input_str.split()))

Example:

list(map(compose2(number_map.get, int), ["1", "2", "7"]))
Out[29]: [-3, -2, None]
```

Obviously in Python 3 you would avoid the explicit conversion to a `list`. A more general approach for function composition in Python can be found [here](https://mathieularose.com/function-composition-in-python/).

(Remark: I came here from the [Design of Computer Programs](https://eu.udacity.com/course/design-of-computer-programs--cs212) Udacity class, to write:)

```
def word_score(word):
    "The sum of the individual letter point scores for this word."
    return sum(map(POINTS.get, word))
```

Answer (score 1):

it's `number_map[int(x)]`, you tried to actually call the map with one argument

Answer (score 0):

Use Square Brackets: --> number_map[int(x)]

```
number_map = { 1: -3, 2: -2, 3: -1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 3 }
input_str = raw_input("Enter something: ")
strikes = [number_map(int(x)) for x in input_str.split()]

***You need to use [] with dictionaries. Use square brackets***
strikes = [number_map[int(x)] for x in input_str.split()]
```