# Checking chars from string using user unput

Tags: python

When I declare the variable for the string in the code it works, for example:

```
messagetoencode="readthis"

encodedMsg=[]

for letter in messagetoencode:
    encodedMsg.append(encode[letter.upper()])

print "result is ", encodedMsg
```

However when I try and do the same operation with the user input it doesn't work:

```
lst = list(raw_input("Please enter a message to encode: "))

encodedMsg=[]

for letter in lst:
    encodedMsg.append(encode[letter.upper()])

print "result is ", encodedMsg
```

and I get a traceback error, any ideas why?

Error:

```
Please enter a message to encode: hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Untitled 3.py", line 27, in <module>
obfuse.append(encode[letter.upper()])
KeyError: 'O'
```

Comment: Can you post the error here?

Comment: By the way, what's the content of `encode`?

Comment: what's the `encode` here?

Comment: I'm actually suprised by the amount of down and close votes. I'm sure the OP will be able to show more info, it has only been 3 minutes.

Comment: The error is clear enough, the `encode` dictionary doesn't contain the key `'O'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the key `O` in the dictionary. It doesn't exist on the text, which is why no error happened. But if you include `o` in your input, you'll get this error.

Well, the *real* solution is to have the key`'O'` in your encoding dictionary.

To deal with unexpected input, you can do a check like this:

```
for letter in lst:
    if letter not in encode:
        raise KeyError("Sorry i don't know how to encode this letter!")
    encodedMsg.append(encode[letter.upper()])
```

Comment: I tried another string and got this "TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable"

Comment: @user1902535 - Are you by any chance using parenthesis instead of square brackets?  In other words, are you doing this `encode(letter.upper())` when you should be doing this `encode[letter.upper()]`?

Comment: There's a lot of errors with your code. Post the whole code here.

Comment: @iCodez - I think that is why it doesnt work, like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634708/typeerror-dict-object-is-not-callable

Comment: @user1902535 Please show us the code you are using and the `encode` dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, `O` is not in the `encode` dictionary. If you want to assign a default value, instead of failing like this, you can use [`dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method like this

```
obfuse.append(encode.get(letter.upper(), None))
```

Now, this will return `None` if any of the keys are not found in `encode`. You might actually want to include a mapping for `O` in your code.

Comment: That is not the problem