# Updating dictionary in python, during gradient descent

Tags: python, dictionary, machine-learning

While updating parameters using gradient descent, I am using

```
for l in range(L):
    parameters["W" + str(l+1)] = parameters["W" + str(l+1)] - learning_rate* grads("dW" + str(l+1))
    parameters["b" + str(l+1)] = parameters["b" + str(l+1)] - learning_rate* grads("db" + str(l+1))
```

but I receive the error that 'dict' object is not callable. How to solve this?

Comment: Need more code to help you out here!

Comment: Not enough code to see what is happening

Comment: Is `grads` a dictionary?  If you change your parentheses to brackets, it may solve the `'dict' object is not callable` error, i.e. `grads['dW' + str(l + 1)]`

Comment: Hii, yes parameters and grads are both dictionaries. I am building a deep neural network from scratch, and I have stored all parameters viz W[l] and b[l] for each layer in parameters, and dW[l] and db[l] for each layer in grads.

Comment: Hii Jonathan, thank you, I was using a wrong parentheses, and your solution worked. Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing values in a dictionary requires brackets `[]`, not parentheses `()` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6634708/6481442).  From the code you've given us, it looks like `grads("db" + str(l+1))` needs to be changed to `grads["db" + str(l+1)]` to fix your error.

A few notes on style:

- [The character lowercase '`l`' shouldn't be used as a variable name](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid) in order to avoid confusion with capital `I` or the number `1`.
- The `a = a - b` pattern can be replaced with `a -= b`.
- Since `str(l+1)` is called so frequently, you might consider saving that string as a variable.