# Q : Error Function 'dict' object is not callable in python

Tags: python, function, dictionary

Recently i starded learning python, this would be my first "useful" script (simple word learning script). I got a "TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable", but it's unrelevant in this case(alteast for me).

```
def discounted_price(total,discount,minprice=100):
    fruits = ['Apple','Avocado','Banana','Blackberries','Blueberries','Cherries','Date Fruit','Grapes','Guava','Jackfruit','Kiwifruit']
    prices = [6,5,3,10,12,7,14,15,8,7,9]
    d1 = dict(zip(fruits,prices))
    chart = ['Blueberries','Blueberries','Grapes','Apple','Apple','Apple','Blueberries','Guava','Jackfruit','Blueberries','Jackfruit']
    fruit_price = None
    counter_item = {}
    for i in chart:
        if i in counter_item:
            counter_item[i] +=1
        else:
            counter_item[i] =1
    counter_item
    fruit_price = {}
    for i, j in d1.items():
        for x, y in counter_item.items():
            if i == x:
                fruit_price[i]=(j*y)
    fruit_price
    total_price = 0
    for i in fruit_price.values():
        total_price += i
    total_price
    minprice=100
    discount=0
    if total_price<minprice:
        discount=total_price
    else:
        discount=total_price*(10/100)
    discounted_price=total_price-discount
    return discounted_price
print(discounted_price(total_price(counter_item(chart),fruit_price),10,minprice=100))
```

```
Type error

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-7dbc173506d2> in <module>
     30     discounted_price=total_price-discount
     31     return discounted_price
---> 32 print(discounted_price(total_price(counter_item(chart),fruit_price),10,minprice=100))

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634708/typeerror-dict-object-is-not-callable
Does this help?

Comment: You are re-using function names as variable names.

Comment: I have tried changing the sign '( )' to '[ ]' but still error sir